# Showing map is linear and finding matrix that describes the map

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations

> Let $A$ be a matrix with $Nul(A) = 0$. For a given vector $b$, there is a unique least squares "solution" $x = T(b)$ of the equation $Ax = b$. Show that the map $T: b \rightarrow T(b) $ is linear. Give the matrix that describes it.

So from what I understand this means I have to show $T(\alpha b) = \alpha T(b)$ and $T(a+b) = T(a) + T(b)$

we have $A^T \alpha b  = \alpha A^T b$ and $A^T(a+b) = A^Ta + A^Tb$. That should prove the map is linear. I guess the matrix that describes the map is $A^T$?

Comment: $Ax=b$, so $x=A^{-1}b=T(b)$

Comment: @W.mu it might be that $A$ not a square matrix, so that $A^{-1}$ cannot exist.

Comment: @drhab You are right. It should be proved by the linearity of $A$ and $nul(A)=0$.

Comment: The matrix that describes the map is $X$ in $x = T(b) = X b$ and that is not $A^T$. For example for a square invertible matrix $A$ we have that if $Ax = b$ then $x = T(b) = A^{-1}b$ so $A^{-1}$ would be the matrix in this special case.

Comment: @Winther oh yea that makes sense. I just got confused because they brought up the least squares method. I guess the the method is same then, just replacing $A^T$ with $A^{-1}$?

Comment: No $A$ need not be square in general so you can't talk about $A^{-1}$. See the answer below and the links within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x$ is the least-squares solution to $A x = b$, one can employ the [normal equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Derivation_of_the_normal_equations) to reformulate this condition as $(A^TA) x = A^T b$. Because $Null(A)=\emptyset$, $A^TA$ is invertible, thus $T = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T$, which basically gives the [pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $A$.